# VBA to send email to an email address in excel depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am completely stuck and wondering if someone could help, please bare with my complete Noobness on VBA.

I have a shared spreadsheet that my team use to keep on track of tasks of documents that need to be rescanned. Please see the screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNA7p.png)

I have code on the sheet that automatically changes column 'M' when an agent enters a value into column A.

Column B (hidden) has a Vlookup which uses an array on a different sheet for the agent in column A's email address.

I've done a bit of research and have tried to create a code that will search in column M for any incompleted/Unactioned work "NO" and automatically send an email reminder to the agent and and email address in columns A and B of the same row (also including the Title Number)

However I just cannot get the code to work.

Any thoughts or suggestions where I'm going wrong?

```
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("M").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value) = "No" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Re-Scan Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "You still have outstanding work on the Rescan Spreadsheet " & _
                        " Title number:  " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value _

                .Display
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be specific: what doesn't work? Note `Cells(cell.Row, "M")` seems redundant - `cell` is already in column M.

Comment: Also - the result of `LCase` can never be equal to `No` (which has an *uppercase* N), perhaps a typo?

Comment: Adding to @BigBen comments, another approach would be to filter column `M` for values with **"No"** and then send emails for all visible rows

Comment: update: it was the uppercase N that was preventing anything from happening. after changing it to "no" it works!

Thanks for you help guys, something so small ey!